How to set up a reviewer group in a GitHub organization?
I am using GitHub Enterprise and I would like to know how to configure a group of reviewers that is automatically assigned when I generate a pull request to the development branch and that at least 1 of them must approve to allow the merge.
I have tried creating a codeowners file in the root of my repository but I see that it is not assigned
/ @stnd-group-gln/NEWOBW


does this doc answer your question, Managing code review settings for your team ?
